# Webclient Mockito fails with a null point on calling retrieve - Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito, webclient

This is how I mock webclient calls

```
`when`(webClientMock.get()).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec::class.java))
        `when`(webClientMock.get().uri("test")).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec::class.java))
        `when`(webClientMock.get().retrieve()).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec::class.java))
        `when`(webClientMock.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(List::class.java)).thenReturn(Mono.just(mockProductSummaryList))
        `when`(webClientMock.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(ProductListResponse::class.java)).thenReturn(Mono.just(ProductListResponse(mockProductSummaryList)))
        `when`(webClientMock.get().retrieve().toEntityList(Product::class.java)).thenReturn(responseEntityMono)
```

The code never passes retrieve() call

```
    return  webClient.get()
        .uri("test")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(ProductListResponse::class.java)
        .block()
```